# graphql elemMatch query in gatsby not returning data

Tags: reactjs, drupal, graphql, drupal-8, gatsby

I have been using drupal 8 as backend which provides json data for my gatsby frontend. Everything is working as expected except one portion.

I have a query like this inside one of my pages:

```
export const pageQuery = graphql`
query($id: String!) {
  articles: allNodeArticle(filter: {relationships: {field_subject: {elemMatch: {id: {eq: $id}}}}}) {

    nodes {
      ...ArticleListInformation
    }
  } 
}
`
```

Nothing is being return eventhough data exists in my backend. This field_subject will have multiple data (like a multiple selection in the backend).

PS: This issue exists just when I build, this is working perfectly in my local version. Also I can see the response in graphiQL appearing fine. Please see the screenshot of the same.

[image]

Could someone help me out with this?

Thanks

Comment: Open up the network inspector (Devtool > Network in Chrome) and verify the contents of `page-data.json` that Gatsby fetches. Make sure that the query data is actually missing.

Comment: Hi @Z.Zlatev thanks for the response. Yes i did check the page-data.json, I can see its empty. Whereas locally I can see data is being shown in the page-data.json perfectly

Comment: I'm seeing the same with Contentful as a back-end: gets the data fine during `develop`, but fails to find data during `build`. Will investigate further.